# Migradoc setting an image next to text

Tags: image, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfsharp, migradoc

I want to float an image on the right of some text in a table cell.

```
cell.AddParagraph("some text");
cell.AddParagraph("next line other text");

Paragraph p = cell.AddParagraph();
p.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
p.Format.RightIndent = 12;
Image image = p.AddImage("image.png");
image.ScaleWidth = 0.07;
```

This code puts the image to the right, but I can't move it up.

```
p.Format.Linespacing = -10;

image.WrapFormat.DistanceTop = -10;
```

These settings did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For moving elements up or down SpaceBefore and SpaceAfter can be used.
In this case:

```
p.Format.SpaceBefore = - 20;
```